# Как сделать похожую анимацию?

Tags: javascript, css, css-animation

Я пытаюсь сделать анимацию, где звёзды бесконечно двигаются с низу в верх.

Звёзды первый раз доходят  до верха и появляются в том же месте, где и появились в самом начале, а мне нужно, чтобы после первого раза они появлялись с низу и шли на верх.

Думаю проблема в `@keyframes`.

```js
let main = document.getElementById('main');

function renderStar(col, classNameStar) {
  for (let i = 0; i < col; i++) {
    main.innerHTML += `<div class="star ${classNameStar}" style="top:${returnRandomInt(window.innerHeight)}px;right:${returnRandomInt(window.innerWidth)}px;"></div>`;
  }
}

function returnRandomInt(max) {
  k = Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
  return k;
}
renderStar(15, 'big-star');
renderStar(75, 'average-star');
renderStar(150, 'small-star');
```

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: radial-gradient( ellipse at bottom, #1b2735 0%, #090a0f 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.star {
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
}

.big-star {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  animation: changePositionStar 20s linear infinite;
}

.average-star {
  width: 3px;
  height: 3px;
  animation: changePositionStar 40s linear infinite;
}

.small-star {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  animation: changePositionStar 60s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes changePositionStar {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(-2000px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main" id="main"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-бы сделать плавную непрерывную анимацию надо задублировать блок анимации, так чтоб начало и конец анимации совпадали. Также надо делать смещение равное высоте видимой области.

В этом примере я вынес время анимации в js, но это просто для удобства. Так делать не обязательно.

```js
let main = document.getElementById('main');

function renderStar(col, time, classNameStar) {
  let html = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < col; i++) {
    html += `<div class="star ${classNameStar}" style="
        top: ${returnRandomInt(window.innerHeight)}px;
        right: ${returnRandomInt(window.innerWidth)}px;
        --time: ${time}s;
      "></div>`;
  }
  main.innerHTML += renderStarGroup(0, html) + renderStarGroup(window.innerHeight, html);
}

function renderStarGroup(top, html) {
  return `<div class="star-group" style="
    top: ${top}px;
    --translateY: -${window.innerHeight}px"
  >${html}</div>`;
}

function returnRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

renderStar(15, 5, 'big-star');
renderStar(75, 10, 'average-star');
renderStar(150, 15, 'small-star');
```

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: radial-gradient( ellipse at bottom, #1b2735 0%, #090a0f 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.star-group {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.star {
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
}

.big-star {
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  animation: changePositionStar var(--time) linear infinite;
}

.average-star {
  width: 3px;
  height: 3px;
  animation: changePositionStar var(--time) linear infinite;
}

.small-star {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  animation: changePositionStar var(--time) linear infinite;
}

@keyframes changePositionStar {
  from {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(var(--translateY));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main" id="main"></div>
```

Comment: Когда открываешь пример на всю страницу, он отображается в углу.

Comment: Ну да, это код автора вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Можно и не создавая сотни элементов, обойтись, например, тремя элементами.

Звезды отрисовываются свойством `box-shadow`.
Два экрана элементов: сами элементы вначале и `::after`-элементы за ними.

Как только `::after`-элементы оказываются все полностью на экране, в этот момент анимация зацикливается: отображаются элементы, а `::after`-элементы уходят вниз.

Таким образом достигается непрерывность анимации.

```js
/* В этой переменной будет время последней генерации стилей */
let recalcLastCall = 0; 

/* В этой переменной будет хзндл таймаута для предотвращения 
   частого множественного запуска перегенерации стилей */
let recalcTimeout = 0; 

/* Запуск генерации стилей для звёзд */
recalc();

/* Повесим перегенерацию стилей на каждое изменение размеров окна */
window.addEventListener('resize',recalc);

/* Функция перегенерации стилей */
function recalc(){
  
  /* Если с момента последней генерации прошло меньше 1 секунды */
  if(Date.now() - recalcLastCall < 1000){
    /* Если таймер отложенного запуска уже задан, то выходим */
    if(recalcTimeout) return;
    /* Запускаем таймер отложенного запуска перегенерации стилей и выходим */
    return recalcTimeout = setTimeout(()=>{
      recalcTimeout = 0;  // принудительно отчищаем хэндл таймаута
      recalc();           // запускаем перегенерацию повторно
    }, 1000 - (Date.now() - recalcLastCall));
  }
  /* Установим время запуска */ 
  recalcLastCall = Date.now();
  
  /* Генерация теней звёзд */
  let farStars = genShadow(200);
  let midStars = genShadow(100);
  let nearStars = genShadow(50);
  
  /* Размещаем генерированный стиль в элемент <style> уже присутсвующий на странице */
  document.querySelector('#style').innerHTML = `
    .far-stars { box-shadow: ${farStars}; }
    .mid-stars { box-shadow: ${midStars}; }
    .near-stars { box-shadow: ${nearStars}; }
    .far-stars::after { box-shadow: ${farStars}; }
    .mid-stars::after { box-shadow: ${midStars}; }
    .near-stars::after { box-shadow: ${nearStars}; }`;
   
  /* Функция генерации теней звёзд имеет один аргумент count - количество звезд */
  function genShadow(count){
    /* Получаем размеры окна */
    let width = window.innerWidth;
    let height = window.innerHeight;
    /* Массив, в который будут сохранены все тени звезд */
    let stars = [];
    /* Цикл генерации теней звезд */
    for(let i = 0; i < count; i++){
      /* Рандомное положение звезды */
      let x = ~~(width * Math.random());
      let y = ~~(height * Math.random());
      /* Прозрачность тени от 8/15 до 15/15 */
      let opacity = ~~(8 * Math.random())+8;
      /* Добавляем тень в массив */
      stars.push(`${x}px ${y}px #fff${opacity.toString(16)}`);
    }
    /* Объединяем тени в одну строку, разделённую запятыми */
    return stars.join(',');
  }
}
```

```css
/* Стиль <body> */
body { margin: 0; }             /* Убрает отступы контента от края окна */

/* Стиль неба */
.sky {
  width: 100vw; height: 100vh; /* Размеры неба - во всё окно */
  background: #000;            /* Цвет неба - чёрный */
  overflow: hidden;            /* Прячем закадровые звёзды */
  position: fixed;             /* Небо устойчиво к прокрутке страницы (на тот случай,
    если количество контента будет превышать размер окна, что активирует прокрутку окна) */
}

/* Стиль для всех звёзд */
.stars {
  z-index: 10;                 /* Слой звезд - 10 */
  animation: animStar 1s linear infinite; /* Ровная бесконечная анимация */
}
/* Стиль дубликатов звезд - Для непрерывной анимации необходимо иметь звезд 
 общей высотой ровно на два экрана. Как только второй экран полностью отображается, 
 а ниже него уже ничего нет, происходит резкая незаметная смена на первый экран.
 И анимация снова поднимает элемент вверх */
.stars::after {
  content: ' ';                /* Необходимо для включения ::after */
  top: 100vh;                  /* Сместит элемент на один экран ниже */
}
.stars, .stars::after {
  border-radius: 50%;          /* Закругляет элементы звёзд */
  position: absolute;          /* Абсолютная позиция для свободного перемещения */
  background: transparent;     /* Невидимый фон для скрытия оригинальных элементов */
}

/* Разные размеры для разных звёзд */
 .far-stars,  .far-stars::after { width: 2px; height: 2px; }
 .mid-stars,  .mid-stars::after { width: 3px; height: 3px; }
.near-stars, .near-stars::after { width: 4px; height: 4px; }

/* Разная скорость для разных звёзд */
.stars.far-stars  { animation-duration: 67s; }
.stars.mid-stars  { animation-duration: 47s; }
.stars.near-stars { animation-duration: 37s; }

/* Кадры анимации перемешения звезд */
@keyframes animStar {
  from { transform: translateY(     0); }
  to   { transform: translateY(-100vh); }
}
```

```html
<!-- Корневой элемент неба, в котором должны отображаться все звезды -->
<div class="sky">
  <div class="stars far-stars"></div>
  <div class="stars mid-stars"></div>
  <div class="stars near-stars"></div>
</div>
<!-- Сюда будет размещён генерированный яваскриптом стиль для отображения звезд -->
<style id="style"></style>
```

Comment: Я видел этот код на codepen. Но не понимаю как с помощью box-shadow можно создать такое количество объектов.

Comment: @Daniil Объект один. Всё что видно на экране - его тени. Несколько теней можно перечислять в `box-shadow` разделяя запятой.

Comment: @Daniil я добавил несколько комментариев. Надеюсь они помогут разобраться. Способ прост как hello world.

Comment: Вам бы учебники писать )). Спасибо за такое подробное объяснение.